# Can I use .equals() on '+'? Not sure why error is being thrown here

Tags: java, html, compiler-construction, syntax-error

This is a syntax analyzer for an HTML markdown language.

I am having trouble figuring out why I am getting an error throw on the following code. The error is throw in the paragraph() method. I am getting the following error: "Exception in thread "main" Exceptions.CompilerException: Syntax Error: paragraph + " So when my syntax analyzer hits the first list item the error is being throw in the paragraph method.

Basically, I have a queue (inputQueue) filled with each string in the following text file, `(#BEGIN, ^, <, The, Simpsons... )` and it should run fine through the following class. The string Tokens.sLIST is declared as "+".

```
'#BEGIN = sHTML'
'^ = sHEAD'
'< = sTITLE'
'> = eTITLE'
'{ = sPARAGRAPH'
'+ = sLIST'
'; = eLIST'
```

text is a..z and special characters which include ':'

Here is the text file:

```
#BEGIN 
^ < The Simpsons > ^ 
{ 
  The members of the The Simpsons are: 
     + Homer Simpson ; 
     + Marge Simpson ; 
     + Bart Simpson ; 
     + Lisa Simpson ; 
     + Maggie Simpson ; 
} 
#END
```

Here is the java class:

```
package edu.towson.cis.cosc455.ctrader.project1.implementation;

import java.util.Arrays;

import Exceptions.CompilerException;

public class SyntaxAnalyzer implements     edu.towson.cis.cosc455.ctrader.project1.interfaces.SyntaxAnalyzer {

@Override
public void markdown() throws CompilerException {
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sHTML)){
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
            head();
            body();
            //System.out.print(Compiler.inputQueue.peek());
            if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.eHTML)){
                System.out.println("Syntax Check complete");
            }else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: .mkd file does not end with #END");
    }else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: .mkd file does not start with #BEGIN");
    return;
}

@Override
public void head() throws CompilerException {
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sHEAD)){
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        title();
        if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.eHEAD)){
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        }
        else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: head");
    }
    else return;
}

@Override
public void title() throws CompilerException {
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sTITLE)){
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        innerText();
        if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.eTITLE)){
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        }
        else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: title");
    }
    else return;
}



@Override
public void body() throws CompilerException {
        paragraph(); 
        innerItem();
        checkSyntax();
}


@Override
public void paragraph() throws CompilerException {

    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sPARAGRAPH)){
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        innerItem();
        if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.ePARAGRAPH)){
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        }
        else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: paragraph " + Compiler.inputQueue.peek());
    }
    else return;

}

@Override
public void innerText() throws CompilerException {
        while(!Arrays.asList(Tokens.TOKENS).contains(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().toUpperCase()))
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
}

@Override
public void variableDefine() throws CompilerException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void variableUse() throws CompilerException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void bold() throws CompilerException {
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sBOLD)){
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        innerText();
        if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.eBOLD)){
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        }
        else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: bold");
    }
    else return;

}

@Override
public void italics() throws CompilerException {
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sITALIC)){
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        innerText();
        if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.eITALIC)){
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        }
        else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: italic");
    }
    else return;

}

@Override
public void listitem() throws CompilerException {
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sLIST)){
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        innerText();
        if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.eLIST)){
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        }
        else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: list item");
    }
    else return;

}

@Override
public void innerItem() throws CompilerException {
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equals(Tokens.sAUDIO))
        audio();
    else if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equals(Tokens.sBOLD))
        bold();
    else if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equals(Tokens.sITALIC))
        italics();
    else if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equals(Tokens.sLINKDESCRIPTION))
        link();
    else if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equals(Tokens.sLIST))
        {System.out.println("here");listitem();}
    else if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equals(Tokens.sAUDIO))
        audio();
    else if(!Arrays.asList(Tokens.TOKENS).contains(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().toUpperCase()))
        innerText();        
    else {innerItem();}


}


@Override
public void link() throws CompilerException {
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sLINKDESCRIPTION)){
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
    innerText();
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.eLINKDESCRIPTION))
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
    else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: list item");

    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sADDRESS))
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
    innerText();
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.eADDRESS))
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
    else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: list item");
    }
  else return;

}

@Override
public void audio() throws CompilerException {
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sAUDIO)){
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        innerText();
        if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sADDRESS)){
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
            innerText();
        if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.eADDRESS))
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        }else throw new CompilerException("error: address");
    }
}

@Override
public void video() throws CompilerException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void newline() throws CompilerException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void checkSyntax() throws CompilerException {
    if(!Arrays.asList(Tokens.TOKENS).contains(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().toUpperCase()) || !Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equals(Tokens.eHTML))
        throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error - Unexpected token: " + Compiler.inputQueue.peek());
}

}
```

Here is the stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" Exceptions.CompilerException: Syntax Error: paragraph +
at edu.towson.cis.cosc455.ctrader.project1.implementation.SyntaxAnalyzer.paragraph(SyntaxAnalyzer.java:68)
at edu.towson.cis.cosc455.ctrader.project1.implementation.SyntaxAnalyzer.body(SyntaxAnalyzer.java:53)
at edu.towson.cis.cosc455.ctrader.project1.implementation.SyntaxAnalyzer.markdown(SyntaxAnalyzer.java:14)
at edu.towson.cis.cosc455.ctrader.project1.implementation.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:57)
```

Comment: Post your stack trace and indicate what line it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handling of `innerItem` is incorrect. If you recognize a '+', you call `listitem`, which consumes all tokens up to and including ';'. After you return, `innerItem` returns into `paragraph`, which fails to look for another inner item and ends up throwing the error.

Remove this line from `innerItem`:

```
 else {innerItem();}
```

This is a fix for `paragraph`:

```
@Override
public void paragraph() throws CompilerException {
    if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sPARAGRAPH)){
        Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        while( onceMore() ){
            innerItem();
        }
        if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.ePARAGRAPH)){
            Compiler.outputQueue.add(Compiler.inputQueue.remove());
        }
        else throw new CompilerException("Syntax Error: paragraph " + Compiler.inputQueue.peek());
    }
    else return;
}
```

As for the condition in the while:

```
boolean onceMore(){
    String next = Compiler.inputQueue.peek();
    return next.equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sAUDIO) ||
           next.equalsIgnoreCase(Tokens.sBOLD) ||
           ...;
}
```

Now I'm not sure about this at all. Normally, I'd expect a list (+...;) to consist of a sequence of identical inner tokens, which means that you need to move the loop into `innerItem`, where `Tokens.sList` is recognized:

```
...
else if(Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equals(Tokens.sLIST)){
    do { listitem();
    } while( Compiler.inputQueue.peek().equals(Tokens.sLIST) );
} ...
```

And the other markups (bold, italic, may occur in any text, even between '+' and ';'. But I don't know the grammar you are trying to implement, so I may be wrong.

Final comment: you and your code would greatly benefit from a few helper methods to abbreviate the eye-boggling expressions, e.g., `void gobble()`, `boolean test(String token)`, `void passthru()`.